# Script not reading end of file new line

Tags: python

I am writing a script to validate if a given file has a blank line at the end or not. I am reading that file into python using code

```
with open(input_file, "r") as file_data:
    for line in file_data:
        if line.strip() == "":
            print "found empty line"
```

When i open the test file in sublime, i can see that sublime shows 370 lines and the 370th line is just an empty line. however, when i use that file as test in my python script, i don't see my `if` condition being true. is python library already skipping an empty-end-of-file-new-line?

**UPDATE**

little bit more context.

The data was generated using linux system. These files were then copied to MAC and were re-process. During this re-processing the data written line by line with command `file_handle.write(data + "\n")`.

I hope this gives more context.

Comment: The newline symbol sits at the end of the last line with content.

Comment: Which platform? Windows text files use newlines to *separate* lines, so you don't have one on the last line of the file (unless there's a blank line at the end), whereas UNIX text files use newlines to *terminate* lines, so no line in a file is valid without a newline after it.

Comment: @wowserx, that's a platform-specific assertion -- not true everywhere.

Comment: @wowserx ... so to validate the files, i have to see if last line ends with new line or not.

Comment: @EmAe, ...I'd tend to suggest to seeking to one byte from the end and reading from there -- that way you'll get only the last byte. Or if you want to detect UNIX text files with an empty line at the end, you'd need to seek to *two* bytes from the end, and see if those bytes are both newlines.

Comment: ...either way, AFAICT, you haven't told us which platform this question revolves around, and that's essential information to either writing an answer or evaluating another answer's correctness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In either case, if there is a single empty last line, the python iterator will read a newline symbol at the end of the last non-empty line. Right?

Comment: its linux/mac shell (data generated on linux system, copied files to mac and now validating them on mac).

Comment: @wowserx, ...that is true in either case *if there's a single empty last line*, yes. OTOH, insofar as the truth of that assumption is what the OP is trying to determine...

Comment: @wowserx added more context to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison for identity with the empty string is a delicate matter. Do this instead:

```
with open(input_file, "r") as file_data:
    for line in file_data:
        if not line.strip():
            print "found empty line"
```

Works for me with Python 3.6.